# Dependency Types - MIPS/Pipelining

Tags: dependencies, mips, pipeline

I need to determine the dependency types present in the following block of instructions.  Unfortunately, the book I'm using is extremely unclear as to how to go about this.  This is what I came up with:

```
SW R16, -100(R6)  --> RAW on R16
LW R4, 8(R16)     --> WAR on R16
ADD R5, R4, R4    --> RAW on R4
```

Am I on the right track?  Can the first instruction have a Read-After-Write dependency type even though it is the first instruction in the pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SW R16, -100(R6)  --> possible RAW on R6 and/or R16
LW R4, 8(R16)     --> none: R16 was read in the previous instruction, 
                      so it can be read safely here

ADD R5, R4, R4    --> RAW on R4
```

Comment: Why is there a possible RAW on R6?  Also, isn't R16 in the first instruction lacking a dependence because we just read R16 in the ID stage and don't use it again until the next instruction's ID stage?

Comment: I'm assuming he means "if they're are instructions before `sw` there may be a RAW dependency"

Comment: So, assuming no instructions prior to the SW, the first two instructions have no dependencies?

Comment: Yes. The `ADD` depends on the `LW`, and there are no other dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The answer would also depend on if these were executing out of order and completing out of order (superscalar) systems.